# Detecting prime numbers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, primes

Can someone please give me guidance on getting the primenumbers here? This is homework so I don't want the answer but some pointers would be greatly appreciated. It's really annoying me :(

I think I'm close. But this problems I have are number 25 and 35. These are not prime but this function is returning them

```
var getPrimeNumber = function(n) {
    if(n === 1) return "";
    else if(n == 2) return 2;
    else if(n == 3) return 3;
    else { 
        for(i=Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n)); i>=2; i--){
            //console.log(i);//maybe another var in here? 
            if(n%i !==0 && n%2 !==0 && n%3 !== 0)
                return n; // 25/Math.sqrt(25) will be equal to zero this is what gives me 25 !!!   
        } 
    }
};
```

Comment: what do you want in return when number is not prime

Comment: Think about the numbers involved. Why is 25 not prime? Why is 35 not prime? How about 49? You'll run into 121 before long too.

Comment: What exactly is this function supposed to do? Get you the first `n` prime numbers, get you all prime numbers till `n`, or check whether `n` is a prime number?

Comment: @Ankit - it currently return "" (blank string)

Comment: @Bergi numbers are passed to this func (1-30 for E.G.) and it returns an array, only it has the number 25 in there which I'm looking to fix. tks for all the other replies I'll work through them

Comment: @HattrickNZ: Could you please add the code how you call this? I still don't get it, `n` is not really an array (is it)?

Comment: For the logic error encountered here see also the followup question [Javascript + return PrimeNumbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17415102/javascript-return-primenumbers)

Comment: Remember, to see if n is prime, you only need to check up to the square root of n.

Comment: Do you need prime numbers for a certain range of numbers? If so just calculate them in a advance and just look them up

Answer (score 19):

Based on [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number#Trial_division), this would be a method for determining if a number is a prime number:

```
function isPrime(number) {
    let start = 2;
    const limit = Math.sqrt(number);
    while (start <= limit) {
        if (number % start++ < 1) return false;
    }
    return number > 1;
}
```

In `node.js` it takes about 250Ms for determining the prime numbers between 2 and 100.000.

[**See also ...**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/gg1kwnfz/embedded/result,js,html,css/)

[**edit aug. 2021**] A somewhat more efficient function. See [this Stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-fkqg5c?file=index.js)

```js
document.querySelector(`pre`).textContent = `Prime numbers < 100\n` +
  [...Array(100)]
  .map((v, i) => isPrime(i) ? i : 0)
  .filter(v => v > 0)
  .join(`\n`);

function isPrime(number) {
  const checkPrime = (nr, limit) => {
    for (let start = 3; start <= limit; start += 2) {
      if (0 === nr % start) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    return nr > 1;
  };

  return number === 2 || number % 2 !== 0 && checkPrime(number, Math.sqrt(number));
}
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: what does this line do? 'return number<=1 ? false : true;'

Comment: It returns false if the given number is smaller then or equals 1. `? :` is a ternary operator, see http://javascript.about.com/od/byexample/a/ternary-example.htm

Comment: why not do "return number > 1;" instead of "return number<=1 ? false : true;"?

Comment: @bstst: well spotted, it's a bit shorter and less complex, edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @KooiInc Nice stuff and very fast. I can get the first 1000 prime numbers after e.g. 2 in less than 1 second, thanks to your suggested code http://jsfiddle.net/albertoarena/j1g1L3kk/1/

Comment: @AlbertoArena: thnx. If you want to see more of it in action, check http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/x7mogd2g/embedded/result,js,html,css/

Comment: It'd help if you explained the code in the answer rather than simply posting code off the internet

Comment: @kooilnc You can perhaps tweak the performance a bit more by checking if a number is divisible by 2 in start, return false. This way later you will need to increment `start` (the divisor) as `start+=2` to skip all even numbers.

Comment: I have another below that I'd like feedback on if possible. It checks if the number meets criteria, before doing any square root calculations.

Comment: @baltoro See my answer below, it is way faster for building a list of primes ;)

Comment: why it is `number % start++ < 1` and not `number % start++ === 0`. please somebody explain.

Comment: @AshishPatel It's just my lazyness, having to type 2 characters less ;)

Answer (score 6):

Here's the fastest way to calculate primes in JavaScript, based on the previous prime value.

```js
function nextPrime(value) {
    if (value > 2) {
        var i, q;
        do {
             i = 3;
             value += 2;
             q = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(value));
             while (i <= q && value % i) {
                 i += 2;
             }
        } while (i <= q);
        return value;
    }
    return value === 2 ? 3 : 2;
}
```

#### Test

```js
var value, result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    value = nextPrime(value);
    result.push(value);
}
console.log("Primes:", result);
```

#### Output

```
Primes: [ 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29 ]
```

It is very fast, because:

- It aligns the loop limit to an integer;
- It uses a shorter iteration loop, skipping even numbers.

It can give you the first 100,000 primes in about 130ms, or the first 1m primes in about 4 seconds.

#### 2021 Update

In this day and age, we should be using [ES6 generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) for this:

```js
// generates "n" primes that follow "startPrime";
function* nextPrimes(startPrime, n) {
    let value = startPrime, i = 0;
    while (i++ < n) {
        if (value > 2) {
            let k, q;
            do {
                k = 3;
                value += 2;
                q = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(value));
                while (k <= q && value % k) {
                    k += 2;
                }
            } while (k <= q);
        } else {
            value = value === 2 ? 3 : 2;
        }
        yield value;
    }
}
```

**test:**

```js
const result = [...nextPrimes(1, 10)];
//=> [2,  3,  5,  7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]
```

```js
function* nextPrimes(startPrime, n) {
let value = startPrime, i = 0;
while (i++ < n) {
    if (value > 2) {
        let k, q;
        do {
            k = 3;
            value += 2;
            q = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(value));
            while (k <= q && value % k) {
                k += 2;
            }
        } while (k <= q);
    } else {
        value = value === 2 ? 3 : 2;
    }
    yield value;
}
}

const result = [...nextPrimes(1, 10)];

display('Primes: ' + result.join(', '));

function display(msg) {
   document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
  'beforeend',
  '<p>' + msg + '</p>'
);
}
```

Comment: nextPrime(7) returns 11 and nextPrime(8) returns 10. I believe this method is quite bugged.

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix if you run the test, you will see it works perfectly. Method `nextPrime` expects that you pass it a prime, that's how it can optimize calculation for the next prime. 8 is not a prime, you should not pass it in. Quote: >Here's the fastest way to calculate primes in JavaScript, based on the previous prime value.

Comment: Ahhh, my bad, I apologize !

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix no worries, and I have just added a code snippet ;)

Comment: I have added a 2021 update, using [ES6 Generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*).

Answer (score 2):

There is a function that will return true if the number is prime and false if it is not:

```
function isPrime(x){     
      d = x-1;
      while (d > 1){
        if ((x % d) == 0) return false;
        d--;
      }
      return true;
    }
```

Checkout the demo: http://jsbin.com/velapabedi/1/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  
  <script>
    function isPrime(x){     
      d = x-1;
      while (d > 1){
        if ((x % d) == 0) return false;
        d--;
      }
      return true;       
      
    }
    
    
    if (isPrime(41)){
      alert('Prime');
    }
    else{
      alert('Not Prime');
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Although it does work, it is quite slow. Doing this Kata (http://www.codewars.com/kata/561e9c843a2ef5a40c0000a4/train/javascript) using this method took over 6 seconds, which prevents the submit.

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix: The link you provided doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a **simple "sieve" for prime numbers,** which can be easily understood, and although it is a *naive approach* (as opposed to sophisticated efficient prime number tests such as the [AKS test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test)), it is pretty fast (10000 numbers tested in < 1 sec). It stores the found prime numbers in the array `prim[]` and tests by using the modulo function (`%`):

The loop tests against already found prime numbers and exits if it is *no prime number,* i.e. if the *modulo result is 0* (regard the expression `i % prim[j])===0`). Otherwise, it adds it to the list of found prime numbers.

**Note** that because the only even prime number is 2, the *loop step is 2* rather then 1, because from 3 onwards there can't be any further even prime numbers.

```js
var MaxNum = 10000;
var prim;

function Main() {
  MaxNum = GetMaxNum();
  prim = CalculatePrimes(MaxNum);
  CheckSome();
}

function CalculatePrimes(pMaxNum) {
  Console.WriteLine("Calculating until " + pMaxNum + "...");
  var _prim = [2];
  if (pMaxNum > 2) {
    for (var i = 3; i < pMaxNum; i += 2) {
      var is_prim = true;
      if (_prim.length > 0) {
        for (var j = 0; j < _prim.length; j++) {
          if ((i % _prim[j]) === 0) {
            is_prim = false;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      if (is_prim) {
        _prim.push(i);
      }
    }
  }
  Console.WriteLine("Prime numbers:");
  for (var i = 0; i < _prim.length; i++) {
    Console.Write(_prim[i] + " ");
  }
  Console.WriteLine();
  Console.WriteLine("Found " + _prim.length + " prime numbers.");
  Console.WriteLine();
  return _prim;
}

// test some individual pre-calculated numbers

function CheckSome() {
  var num1 = prim[prim.length - 1];
  var num2 = num1 - 1;
  Console.WriteLine("Test: " + num1.toString() + ". Is it a prime number? " + Is_prime(num1));
  Console.WriteLine("Test: " + num2.toString() + ". Is it a prime number? " + Is_prime(num2));
}

function Is_prime(n) {
  if (n > MaxNum) throw "ERROR: n must be <" + MaxNum + "!";
  if (prim.indexOf(n) === -1)
    return false;
  else
    return true;
};


// ------------ HELPERS to display on screen ------------
var Console = {
  Section: 1,
  SectionId: "#section1",
  NewSection: function() {
    var $currentSection = $(this.SectionId);
    this.Section++;
    this.SectionId = "#section" + this.Section.toString();
    $currentSection.before('<div id="section' + this.Section.toString() + '"></div>');
  },
  Write: function(str) {
    $(this.SectionId).append(str);
  },
  WriteLine: function(str) {
    if (str !== undefined && str !== null && str !== "") this.Write(str);
    this.Write("<br/>");
  }
};


var GetMaxNum = function() {
  var result = $("#MaxNumSelect option:selected").val();
  return result;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#MaxNumSelect").change(function() {
    MaxNum = GetMaxNum();
    Console.NewSection();
    Main();
    Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------");
  });
  Main();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Select max number:&nbsp;
  <select id="MaxNumSelect">
    <option value="10000" default="default">10000</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
    <option value="1000">1000</option>
    <option value="100000">100000</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="results">
  <div id="section1"></div>
</div>
```

In the above example, we have tested the first 10000 natural numbers. To decide if a given number is a prime number, you simply check if it is contained in the array `prim`:

```js
function Is_prime(n) {
    if (n>MaxNum) throw "ERROR: n must be <"+CalcToNum+"!";
    if (prim.indexOf(n)===-1)
      return false;
    else
      return true;
};
```

Of course, in order for this to work the prime numbers need to be pre-calculated.

**Example:** `alert(Is_prime(25));` - returns false, because 25 is no prime number.

**Note:** The number range must be checked, because the function `Is_prime` can decide only for numbers which are previously tested by the sieve above. If the array is too small for the number to check (i.e. if not enough prime numbers are pre-calculated), an error is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I considered the following in my implementation: [Prime numbers are "natural numbers"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number) and [it is possible for negative values to be prime numbers](https://primes.utm.edu/notes/faq/negative_primes.html). This is a more definitive solution with input sanitation:

```js
function isPrime(num) {
    //check if value is a natural numbers (integer)
    //without this check, it returns true
    if (isNaN(num) || num % 1 !== 0) {
        return false;
    }
    num = Math.abs(num); //*negative values can be primes
    if (num === 0 || num === 1) {
        return false;
    }
    var maxFactorNum = Math.sqrt(num);
    for (var i = 2; i <= maxFactorNum; i++) {
        if (num % i === 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

//checking anomalies
console.log(isPrime(1.22));
console.log(isPrime(1.44));
console.log(isPrime("string"));

console.log("All prime numbers from 1-1000:");
var arr = [];
for (var i = 1; i < 1000; i++) if (isPrime(i)) arr.push(i);
console.log(arr.join`, `);
```

I hope my answer proves to be more readable code that also uses best practices. For example, some answers leave the square root calculation in the loop causing the method to run that calculation on every loop.

Answer (score -1):

You should return a `bool` value and new function can be:

```
function(n) {
    if(n === 1) { return false;}
    else if(n == 2) { return true;}
    else if(n == 3) { return true;}
    else { 
        for(i=Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n));i>=2;i--){
            //console.log(i);//maybe another var in here? 
                if(n%i ==0 || n%2 ==0 || n%3 == 0) {return false;} 
        } 
        }
    return true;
};
```

In the OP, the control `if(n%i !==0 && n%2 !==0 && n%3 !== 0) {return n;}` was problematic because even if only single `i` satisfies this condition, the function returns the number as prime.

Comment: and might call the function isPrimeNumber() (imo)

Answer (score -1):

In your if statement you got

```
if(n%i !==0 && n%2 !==0 && n%3 !== 0)
```

you for loop is going till i >= 2, so the n%2 !== 0 is useless, when i = 2, your if would look like:

```
if(n%2 !==0 && n%2 !==0 && n%3 !== 0)
```

Thats 2x the same check, the same is for n%3, its already checked :).

you should keep a bool to check the n%i !== 0, if it never reach this it's a prime.

Good luck with your homework :).

Answer (score -1):

This is my Answer

```js
var isPrime = function (n) {
  if (n < 2) {
    return false;
  } else if (n === 2) {
    return true;
  }
  for (var i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    if (n%i === 0) {
      return false;
    } else if (i === n-1) {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
console.log(isPrime(7));
```

Comment: What's the need for the second "else if" statement though? Why didn't you just return true if the above was false?

Answer (score -1):

```
function isPrime(number) {

  // Immediate exit cases
  switch(true){
    case (number < 2):
      return console.log("Please enter a number greater than or equal to 2.")
    case (number === 2 || number === 3):
      return console.log(number + " is a prime number!")
  }

  // Process number if it does not meet above requirements
  var num = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(number))

  for(var i = 2; i <= num; i++) {
    if(number % i === 0)
      return console.log(number + " is not a prime number")
    else
      return console.log(number + " is a prime number!")
  } 
}

isPrime(27) // 27 is a prime number!
isPrime(30) // 30 is not a prime number
isPrime(55) // 55 is a prime number!
isPrime(2)  // 2 is a prime number!
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the below code. It checks if the number is prime and if it isn't it logs the number's lowest divisor. It is accurate for numbers with less than 17 **digits** (this theoretically would work for any number but the way JavaScript works means that this isn't true). You can try it out embedded into a website here: https://prime-number-checker-git-main.matt-destroyer.vercel.app/
Or in the snippet below.

```js
function check() {
    function checkIfPrime(number) {
        if (number < 1) {
            i = 'less than zero or the number you entered was zero';
            return false;
        } else if (number < 2) {
            i = 'itself only';
            return false;
        } else if (number % 2 === 0) {
            i = 2;
            return false;
        } else if (number < 10) {
            if (number === 3) {
                return true;
            } else if (number === 5) {
                return true;
            } else if (number === 7) {
                return true;
            }else if (number === 9) {
                i = 3;
                return false;
            } 
        } else if (number % 3 === 0) {
            i = 3;
            return false;
        } else if (number % 5 === 0) {
            i = 5;
            return false;
        } else if (number % 7 === 0) {
            i = 7;
            return false;
        } else {
            i = 4;
            while (i * i < number) {
                if (number % i === 0) {
                    return false;
                }
                i += 2;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    let i = 0;
    let input = parseInt(prompt('Enter a number to check if it is prime:'));
    if (input < 0) {
        alert(input + ' is not a prime number. A prime number must be a positive integer.');
    } else if (input === "") {
        alert("You cannot check if 'BLANK' is prime.");
    } else if (input != Math.round(input)) {
        alert(input + ' is not a prime number. A prime number cannot be a decimal.');
    } else {
        let check = checkIfPrime(input);
        if (check === true) {
            alert(input + ' is a prime number.');
        } else {
            alert(input + ' is not a prime number. Its lowest divisor is ' + i + '.');
        }
    }
}
check();
```

Answer (score -1):

I barely understand people's code, so here is mine (idk if they are not too clean but i think it's very easy to understand)

```
    function primeNum (x){
    const primeArray =[];

    for (var i = 1 ; i <= x ; i++){
        if (x % i === 0){
            primeArray.push(i)
        }
    }

    if (primeArray.length === 2){
        return "it's a prime boys"
    } else {
        return "it's not a prime sorry to say"
    }
}
```

the concept is simple, prime number is a number that only can **divied by only 2 numbers** and has **modulo equal to 0** (`x % i === 0`). So if the `primeArray` has length more than 2 (more than 2 numbers), it's not a prime number.

i don't know what people says about my code, i need your advice guys. Best Regards.

Answer (score -4):

Do you want to know how to determine a number is prime or composite. This code make you understand easily. Input from a number 2.

```
var p = prompt("Insert a number for check","");
var x = " is a prime number";
for(i=2; i<p; i++){
    if(p%i === 0){
        x = " is a composite number";
        break;
    }
}
alert(p+x);
```

Comment: Why `i < p`? Why not `i < Math.floor(p/2)`?