# Javascript + return PrimeNumbers

Tags: javascript, numbers

I am trying to write a function that returns the PrimeNumber. for testing purposes i am just doing a console.log for stages of this function, to try and understand it better. 
so this line(line:18) in my total function will just return i; as opposed to do a console.log 
So Basically, 30 will be passed to the function and the function will return every prime number <=30.

It is based on this from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number#Trial_division): 
This routine consists of dividing n by each integer m that is greater than 1 
and less than or equal to the square root of n. 
If the result of any of these divisions is an integer, 
then n is not a prime, otherwise it is a prime.

**(Question here: 25/Math.sqrt(25) = 0, therefore NotPrime
BUT 25/2=12.5, 25/3=8.3333 25/4=6.25 => IsPrime as 12.5 is not an integer Or am I mising something here???)**

there is also the problem of duplication: 13 is printed twice because 13/2 and 13/3 is executed. **Question here: I would like to fix this duplication also?**

```
function isInt(n) {
   return n % 1 === 0;
}

var test = 25
console.log(Math.sqrt(test));

function prime(n) {
for(var i = 1; i <= n; i++) 
{   if(i%2 !==0 && i%3 !==0){ // if i/2 does not have a remainder it might be a prime so go to next line else jump 

to next number and i%3 the same 
        var a = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(i));
        for(j = 2; j<=a; j++){ 

            console.log(i + "/" + j); //print j//it prints 9 twice and 10 twice 
            console.log("==" + i/j);                    //because the sqrt of 9 = 3 => 

for j= 2 and j=3 
            if(isInt(i/j)) {}
            else{console.log("----"  + i + "is Prime");}
        }
    }
}
};

prime(test);
```

Another example here using aslightly different method: but again I have the same problem as the above 25 and duplication

```
var test = 25
console.log(Math.sqrt(test));

for(var i = 1; i <= test; i++) 
{   if(i%2 !==0 && i%3 !==0){ // if i/2 does not have a remainder it might be a prime so go to next line else jump to next number and i%3 the same 
        var a = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(i));
        for(j = 2; j<=a; j++){ 

            console.log(i + "%" + j); //print j//it prints 9 twice and 10 twice 
            console.log("==" + i%j);                    //because the sqrt of 9 = 3 => for j= 2 and j=3 
            if(i%j !==0) {
                console.log("----"  + i + "is Prime");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

[EDIT]Thank you all very much for pointing out my flaws/mistakes
here is my working example. Thank you all again!!

```
function isInt(n) {
   return n % 1 === 0;
}

var test = 100
console.log(Math.sqrt(test));

function prime(n) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        var a = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(i));
        var bool = true;
        for(j = 2; j<=a; j++) { 

            if(!isInt(i/j)) {
                //console.log(i+"/"+j+"=="+i/j+", therefore "+i+" is Prime");
            } else {bool = false;}
        }
        if(bool) {console.log(i+"/"+j+"=="+i/j+", therefore "+i+" is Prime");}
    }
}
prime(test);
```

Comment: This isn't a particularly efficient way to go about this

Comment: Read carefully: *"If the result of **any** of these divisions is an integer, then n is not a prime, otherwise it is a prime."* That is you have to dived the number by **every** integer between 2 and the square root (inclusive) and if **one** of the divisions result in an integer, the number is not prime. `25/5 = 5`, hence not prime.

Comment: `25/Math.sqrt(25) = 0` are you sure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 25/Math.sqrt(25) = 0, therefore NotPrime
>
> BUT 25/2=12.5, 25/3=8.3333 25/4=6.25 => IsPrime

No. Only because it neither is divisible by 2, 3, and 4, it does not mean that 25 is a prime number. It must be divisible by *nothing* (except 1 and itself) - but 25 is divisible by 5 as you noticed. You will have to check against that as well.

> 13 is printed twice because 13/2 and 13/3 is executed.
>
> Question here: I would like to fix this duplication also?

Your logic is flawed. As above, just because a number is not divisible by an other number that does *not* mean it was prime - but your code prints results based on that condition. Instead, is has to be not divisible by **all** other numbers.

You just have an extra condition that nothing that is divisible by 2 or 3 enters the loop, but everything that is divisible by 5, 7, 11 etc (and not divisible by 2 or 3) is yielded. 25 is just the first number to occur in that series, the next ones will be 35 and 49.

Actually you're already testing 2 and 3 in the loop from `2` to `a` already, so you should just omit that condition. You would've noticed your actual problem much faster then if you had tried:

```
function prime(n) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        var a = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(i));
        for(j = 2; j<=a; j++) { 
            if(!isInt(i/j)) {
                console.log(i+"/"+j+"=="+i/j+", therefore "+i+" is Prime");
            }
        }
    }
}
prime(25);
```

The logic should be: Test all divisors from `2` to `sqrt(i)`, and if `i` is divisible by any of them you know that it's not a prime. Only if it has passed the loop with **none of them** being a factor of `i`, you know **in the end** that it's a prime. I'll leave that as an exercise to you :-)