# Web Worker Prime number calculation

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I am trying to create a HTML 5 Web Worker that will calculate the number of prime numbers (staring from 1) for a given value: My JavaScript code is:

```
var found = 0;
var n = 1;
var total = 0;
var THRESHOLD = 10;

while (total < THRESHOLD) {
n += 1;
for (var i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
    if (!(n % i == 0)) {
        total++;
        postMessage(found);
    }
    else {
        found++;
    }
 }
}
```

This code is based on:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/250102/An-HTML-progressbar-using-web-workers
However, the Web Worker script returns the value 8, which obviously is incorrect for the input number 10. Where I am going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong , you can only sure about prime number if it is not divisible till the end. If it is divisible in between it is not prime.I have updated the code below.

```
                       var found = 0;
                       var n = 1;
                       var total = 0;
                       var THRESHOLD = 10;

                      while (total < THRESHOLD) {
                       n += 1;
                       found = 0 ;
                       for (var i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
                       if ((n % i == 0)) {
                       found = 1;
                       break;
                       }

                       }
                       if(found == 0)
                              total++;
                              postMessage(found);
                       }
```

Comment: I tested the code. But irrespective of any THRESHOLD value I provide, the worker.onmessage event handler on the main page always receives the value 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the prime number determination outside:

```
var n = 0
   ,total = 0;
   ,THRESHOLD = 10;

while (++n < THRESHOLD) {
  total += isPrime(n) ? 1 : 0;
}

postMessage(total); //=> 4

function isPrime(number) {
    var start = 2;
    while (start <= Math.sqrt(number)) {
        if (number % start++ < 1) return false;
    }
    return number > 1;
}
```

See [**this SO answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17389350/prime-numbers-javascript/17390131#17390131) for the `isPrime` function

Here's a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/x7mogd2g/) for this code to play with

Comment: Tested the code. For a THRESHOLD value of 10 it returns 29, which is incorrect. Also, I want the number of prime numbers, not their sum. For example, the script should postMessage the value 5 (1, 2, 3, 5, 7) for THRESHOLD value of 10.

Comment: Ok. See edited answer then. BTW: 1 is not a prime number, see https://primes.utm.edu/notes/faq/one.html. So postMessage for a THRESHOLD value of 10 should return **4**.

Comment: Ok, glad I could be of assistance ;)